# Mysql update column based on a string from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a column called `PrebookCB` in a table called `Workorders` and set it to 1 if the CustomerStatus column in Table `Customers` equals the string 'Good - Prebook'.  I have tried various joins ect and cant seem to get it to work. This seems to be the closest. there would be multiple Workorders for each customer. Workorders have a column called CustomerID that matches the Customers primary index column called CustomerID

```
UPDATE Workorders
       JOIN Customers
       ON Workorders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
SET    Workorders.PrebookCB = 1
WHERE  Customers.CustomerStatus = 'Good - Prebook'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Update Workorders
set prebookCB = 1
where CustomerID in (select customerid from customers 
where customeerstatus='Good-Prebook')
```

In this, the UPDATE works on you desired table. WHERE filters the records to update by comparing the customerID to be present in the result of a subquery. The subquery, further filters and select customerID from the customers table only when they have the apt status.

Hope this helps to explain !

Comment: How this answer differ from rakeshjain's answer

Comment: Foe some reason 0 rows are affected but I know that 290 customers have the CustomerStatus of 'Good - Prebook'. What else could be affecting it?

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan , I was typing, when the answer was posted, so did not know.

Comment: @user2120901 , well I can't directly point out the problem as I don't have the defining structures of your tables. On the other hand, try and confirm the Integrity and equivalence of the customerID attribute. The customerID shoulld also be present equivalently in the workorders table. If you can, give more details of your tables structure.

Comment: If I remove the last line, WHERE CustomerStatus ='Good-Prebook', then it updates all 6,000 records so I know the CustomerID is matching.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this

```
UPDATE Workorders SET PrebookCB = 1 
WHERE CustomerID IN 
    (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerStatus = 'Good - Prebook')
```

Comment: For some reason 0 rows are affected but I know that 290 customers have the CustomerStatus of 'Good - Prebook'. What else could be affecting it?

Comment: Can you just run "SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE CustomerStatus = 'Good - Prebook'" query to check that you are getting those 290 rows?